# Ensuring that optimization does not find the trivial solution by setting weights to 0

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization, computer-vision, pytorch

I am trying to train a neural network which takes as input (`input_t0`) and an initial hidden state (call it `s_t0`) and produces a new hidden state (`s_t1`) by transforming the input via a series of transformations (neural network layers). At the next time step, a transformed input (`input_t1`) and the hidden state from the previous time step (`s_t1`) is passed to the same model. This process keeps repeating for a couple of steps.

The goal of optimization is to ensure the distance between `s_t0` and `s_t1` is small through self-supervision, as `s_t1` is supposed to be an transformed version of `s_t0`. In other words, I want `s_t1` to only carry new information in the new input. My intuition tells me taking the norm of the weights and ensuring the norm does not go to zero (is this even possible?) would be one way to achieve this. However, I'm afraid won't be the best thing to do necessarily, as it might not encourage the model to update the state vector with new information.

Currently the way I train the model is by taking the absolute distance between `s_t0` and `s_t1` via `loss = torch.abs(s_t1 - s_t0).mean(dim=1)`. Then I call `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()` which changes the weights. Note that the reason that I use `abs()` is that the hidden states are produced after applying ReLU, so the only hold positive values. So what is the best way to achieve this and ensure the weights don't go to 0?  Would I be able to somehow use mutual information for this?

However, I noticed that optimization quickly finds the trivial solution by setting weights to 0. This causes both `s_t0` and `s_t1` get smaller and smaller until their difference is 0, which satisfies the constraint but does not yield the behavior I expect. Is there a way to ensure weights do not go to zero during optimization?

Comment: Is there no other objective than ensuring the hidden states are near equal? No constraints or requirements from the input? As formulated, your network is behaving correctly -- you have defined your loss such that you ask the network to optimize weights to keep the hidden states equal, and to ignore the input. So that is what it does. If your objective is different, you need to specify that in addition.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Sorry I think I didn't make things very clear. The hidden states are transformations of the input. So there is some dependence on the input for sure. Is that what you meant by "No constraints or requirements from the input"?

Comment: If the hidden state is a transformation of the input, is there some input dependent property it must satisfy? If so, that must be a part of the optimization, and would be reflected in the loss. In the current formulation, you basically tell the network:  "here's the input and hidden state, make the output close to the hidden state, irrespective of what the input is". So the network learns to simply ignore the input and to make the output exactly equal to the hidden state.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Isn't somehow possible to use a mutual information loss to enforce this constraint indirectly instead of adding an explicit term to the loss function to ensure the hidden states are dependent on the inputs? I'm afraid even such explicit term would not be very beneficial as the eventual goal is to reduce discrepancy between the hidden states, and optimization will quickly figure out that reducing the weight vector values would potentially be the best shortcut to achieve that. Correct me if I'm wrong.